# Vega Lite - Layered chart with only one X label instead of two

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, deneb

I'm trying to replicate this graphic from excel to power bi by using deneb and vega lite:
[image: Original Graphic]

but I'm getting this result:

[image: Deneb - Vega Lite]

Here is the code I have until now:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "area",
        "line": {"color": "orange"},
        "color": {
          "x1": 1,
          "y1": 1,
          "x2": 1,
          "y2": 0,
          "gradient": "linear",
          "stops": [
            {
              "offset": 0,
              "color": "orange"
            },
            {
              "offset": 1,
              "color": "orange"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "timeUnit": "yearmonth",
          "field": "Displayed Month",
          "title": null,
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"labels": true}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"labels": true},
          "title": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "width": {"band": 0.3}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "timeUnit": "yearmonth",
          "field": "Displayed Month",
          "axis": {"labels": true},
          "type": "temporal",
          "title": null
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Sum of Open items",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"labels": true},
          "title": null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {
    "scale": {
      "x": "shared",
      "y": "independent"
    },
    "axis": {
      "x": "shared",
      "y": "independent"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use the resolve option in vega lite to get the marks aligned on the same X axis but without success - could you please give me some hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could something like this work for you?
There are always plenty of alternatives with vega lite - it's just about finding a solution that works for you.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-01-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5000,
        "Sum of Open items": 100
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-02-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5200,
        "Sum of Open items": 110
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-03-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 4800,
        "Sum of Open items": 95
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-04-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5300,
        "Sum of Open items": 120
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-05-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5500,
        "Sum of Open items": 105
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-06-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5400,
        "Sum of Open items": 110
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-07-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5700,
        "Sum of Open items": 115
      }
    ]
  },
  "width": 250,
  "height": 250,
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "area",
        "line": {"color": "orange"},
        "color": {
          "x1": 1,
          "y1": 1,
          "x2": 1,
          "y2": 0,
          "gradient": "linear",
          "stops": [
            {"offset": 0, "color": "orange"},
            {"offset": 1, "color": "orange"}
          ]
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Displayed Month",
          "title": null,
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"labels": true},
          "scale": {"nice": false, "padding": 15}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"labels": true},
          "title": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": {"band": 1}},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Displayed Month",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "labelAlign": "center",
            "labelExpr": "[timeFormat(datum.value, '%b'), timeFormat(datum.value, '%m') == '01' ? timeFormat(datum.value, '%Y') : '']",
            "labelPadding": 5,
            "tickSize": 0,
            "gridDash": {
              "condition": {
                "test": {"field": "value", "timeUnit": "month", "equal": 1},
                "value": []
              },
              "value": [2, 2]
            }
          }
        },
        "opacity": {"value": 0.7},
        "y": {
          "field": "Sum of Open items",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"labels": true},
          "title": null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "shared", "y": "independent"}},
  "config": {}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @APB Reports - but this seems to work only for data with 7 or more months, but for my example, when I add only 3 months, the labels get multiplied - any idea why?

Comment: I just tested my solution with months back to 2022-08-01 and it works fine.

Comment: but how many months? did u select only 3? nevertheless I will take your answer as it fixed half of the issue, the other part must be from my data, but ghen again i've tested your solution with the data you provided, but only 3 months instead of 7.

Comment: Try and increase the width to 350. With temporal type the axis labels can automatically hide if the chart is too small.

Comment: Finally! Apparently fixing the width did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy charting

Answer (score 0):

I have now added more months and increased the size of the chart.
I also updated the bar x axis based on spec:
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/timeunit.html

```
"type": "temporal",
"timeUnit": "yearmonth",
"bandPosition": 0,
```

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2022-07-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 6000,
        "Sum of Open items": 120
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2022-08-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 7000,
        "Sum of Open items": 130
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2022-09-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 4000,
        "Sum of Open items": 100
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2022-10-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 6000,
        "Sum of Open items": 150
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2022-11-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 3000,
        "Sum of Open items": 140
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2022-12-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5000,
        "Sum of Open items": 110
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-01-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5000,
        "Sum of Open items": 120
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-02-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5200,
        "Sum of Open items": 110
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-03-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 4800,
        "Sum of Open items": 95
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-04-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5300,
        "Sum of Open items": 120
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-05-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5500,
        "Sum of Open items": 105
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-06-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5400,
        "Sum of Open items": 110
      },
      {
        "Displayed Month": "2023-07-01",
        "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open": 5700,
        "Sum of Open items": 115
      }
    ]
  },
  "width": 450,
  "height": 250,
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "area",
        "line": {"color": "#148FE8"},
        "color": {
          "x1": 1,
          "y1": 1,
          "x2": 1,
          "y2": 0,
          "gradient": "linear",
          "stops": [
            {"offset": 0, "color": "#fff"},
            {"offset": 1, "color": "#148FE8"}
          ]
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Displayed Month",
          "title": null,
          "type": "temporal",
          "timeUnit": "yearmonth",
          "axis": {"labels": true},
          "scale": {"nice": false, "padding": 10}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Sum of EUR Total Amnt Open",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"labels": true},
          "title": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": {"band": 0.7}},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Displayed Month",
          "type": "temporal",
          "timeUnit": "yearmonth",
          "bandPosition": 0,
          "axis": {
            "labelAlign": "center",
            "labelExpr": "[timeFormat(datum.value, '%b'), timeFormat(datum.value, '%m') == '01' ? timeFormat(datum.value, '%Y') : '']",
            "labelPadding": 5,
            "tickSize": 5,
            "gridDash": {
              "condition": {
                "test": {"field": "value", "timeUnit": "month", "equal": 1},
                "value": []
              },
              "value": [2, 2]
            }
          }
        },
        "opacity": {"value": 0.7},
        "color": {"value": "#6B6A6A"},
        "y": {
          "field": "Sum of Open items",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"labels": true},
          "title": null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "shared", "y": "independent"}},
  "config": {}
}
```

[image]